# Gtk-WARNING **: Content added to the action area of a dialog using header bars

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

This warning appears when I add a custom `Gtk.Box` in a `Gtk.Stack`.

```
class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    """
    Class that inherits of Gtk.ApplicationWindow and that represents the main window application
    """

    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(application=app)

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder.new_from_file(UIS_PATH + 'main_window.xml')

        self.set_titlebar(self.builder.get_object('mw_headerbar'))
        self.add(self.builder.get_object('mw_main_vbox'))

        stack = self.builder.get_object('mw_main_stack')
        stack.add_titled(PersonsFom(self), 'persons_form', 'Gestão de Pessoas')

        sidebar = Gtk.StackSidebar()
        sidebar.set_stack(stack)
        sidebar.set_size_request(200, -1)
        mw_main_hbox = self.builder.get_object('mw_main_hbox')
        mw_main_hbox .pack_start(sidebar, expand=False, fill=True, padding=0)
        mw_main_hbox.reorder_child(sidebar, 0)
```

The warning appears when the execution flow is line `stack.add_titled(PersonsFom(self), 'persons_form', 'Gestão de Pessoas')`. `PersonsForm` is a sub-class of `Gtk.Box` containing several components such as `buttons`, `Boxes`, `Grids`, `Entries`, ...
I do not understand what you mean this warning.

The `MainWindow` class has [parts](https://paste.gnome.org/pet6bn0tk) built with glade file and `PersonsForm` has [too](https://paste.gnome.org/pmykewjtn).
I will also leave the `PersonsForm` [code](https://paste.gnome.org/pddxj4ctg).

The git [repository](https://github.com/matheusssilva/PyLoca).

Comment: Show your glade file.

Comment: FTR, I've been getting the same error with Glade from Arch repos *(there were also others, and the window didn't appear)* till upgraded the system.

Comment: Are you sure the message shows up with that code? Because looking through your repository I see an `images_chooser_dialog`... and I'm not sure what else is adding things to a dialog

Comment: Yes! It is showed.
But if I create the `Gtk.HeaderBar` by python code and remove the `HeaderBar` in the glade file, the error is not showing.

Sorry for delay.

Comment: In fact I think it's a bug in GTK 3.20. I did run the code without making changes on GTK 3.18 and the error does not appear.